# How to import an Android project in to eclipse with out creating a new one from source?

Tags: android, eclipse, svn

I would like to import a project in to Eclipse without having to "create a new project from the source". So that I can use folder and files with subversion from a project that is already in development that I have checked out. Eclipse with import the project but leaves out the androidmanifest.xml and the R.java is not generated.

This doesn't work for me:

Solved: If you want to "Create project from existing source", you need to create a new directory and then put the project directory tree into that new directory. Then point to the new directory when importing.
*I found the solution on a Korean website, that's why I missed my first search with google.

Answer (score 1):

Solved: Turns out the .png files in the /res folder were causing errors, so the R.java file wasnt being generated( [R cannot be resolved - Android error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error) ). I re-saved them as .png files and over wrote the originals and that fixed that problem.

Also when imported I did ctrl+shift+o and it added import R.java witch needed to be deleted.

I then was getting an error that was fixed by this post: ["Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" on external JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar)