# Android Spring Integration

Tags: java, android, spring, mobile

I am facing an issue while trying to use the spring android framework. I have tried the samples according to [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring-android/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/rest-template.html) link. Actually I can't get it to work. Because when I try to import the `spring-android-rest-template-1.0.0.M1.jar` and `spring-android-commons-logging-1.0.0.M1.jar` it gives an error saying

> Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

Therefore I was not able to complete the sample program.

I have downloaded the the jar files separately. It gives no errors in the code. But a top level error is generating.

Why is this error occurring, has anyone else got the same issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting the same error too, used the solution noted here: 
["Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" on external JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar) removing all libraries from build path, clean and rebuild, then adding just the spring-android-rest-template-1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: Hi scotty,
Yes you are correct, however when i posted this issue in the spring community they have accepted that there was an issue and tracked the bug in their bug tracker. Now it has been fixed i think.