# (Android) Proguard can't find dynamically referenced class javax.swing.*

Tags: android, proguard

I have a problem with Proguard and use of external libraries. My project compiles without errors and runs successfully on a real device, 
but only when I run it from Eclipse. Now I want to make an obfuscated release version so I did the following:
ran "android update project -p ./"
added

```
proguard.dir=/home/stoned/android-sdk-linux_86/proguard4.5.1/lib
proguard.config=/home/stoned/workspace/Fidoo/proguard.cfg
```

when I run "ant release" I get the following:

```
... skipped many irrelevant messages ...

-obfuscate:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/stoned/workspace/Fidoo/bin/proguard
      [jar] Building jar: /home/stoned/workspace/Fidoo/bin/proguard/original.jar
 [proguard] ProGuard, version 4.4
 [proguard] ProGuard is released under the GNU General Public License. The authors of all
 [proguard] programs or plugins that link to it (com.android.ant, ...) therefore
 [proguard] must ensure that these programs carry the GNU General Public License as well.
 [proguard] Reading input...
 [proguard] Reading program jar [/home/stoned/workspace/Fidoo/bin/proguard/original.jar]
 [proguard] Reading program jar [/home/stoned/workspace/Fidoo/libs/exapi-1.16.jar]
 [proguard] Reading program jar [/home/stoned/workspace/Fidoo/libs/libthrift.jar]
 [proguard] Reading program jar [/home/stoned/workspace/Fidoo/libs/log4j-1.2.14.jar]
 [proguard] Reading library jar [/home/stoned/android-sdk-linux_86/platforms/android-4/android.jar]
 [proguard] Initializing...
 [proguard] Warning: org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.categoryexplorer.CategoryNodeRenderer: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeCellRenderer
 [proguard] Warning: org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.categoryexplorer.TreeModelAdapter: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.event.TreeModelListener
 [proguard] Warning: org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$32: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.event.ActionListener
 [proguard] Warning: org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$31: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.event.ActionListener

... skipped many lines of similar messages ...

 [proguard] Note: org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.categoryexplorer.CategoryAbstractCellEditor: can't find dynamically referenced class javax.swing.event.CellEditorListener
 [proguard] Note: org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.categoryexplorer.CategoryAbstractCellEditor: can't find dynamically referenced class javax.swing.event.CellEditorListener
 [proguard] Note: org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.categoryexplorer.CategoryAbstractCellEditor: can't find dynamically referenced class javax.swing.event.CellEditorListener
 [proguard] Note: org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.categoryexplorer.CategoryAbstractCellEditor: can't find dynamically referenced class javax.swing.event.CellEditorListener
 [proguard] Note: org.apache.log4j.spi.LocationInfo: can't find dynamically referenced class com.ibm.uvm.tools.DebugSupport
 [proguard] Note: there were 5 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
 [proguard]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
 [proguard] Warning: there were 1656 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
 [proguard]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars'),
 [proguard]          or perhaps the '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses' option.
```

Obviously, javax.swing. classes are not needed in Android application, as well as log4j classes. How do I make proguard not to search for those referenced libraries?

Answer (score 22):

If there is no version of log4j without the Swing dependencies, and if you can't easily add a filter on the jar in the build process, the cleanest solution is to switch off just these particular warnings in proguard.cfg:

```
-dontwarn org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.**
-dontnote org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.**
```

You'll then still get any other warnings that might be relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you put log4j into your classpath (libs/log4j-1.2.14.jar). That's why log4j is included. It is also pulling in references to javax.swing.

Comment: My project uses external library, which uses libthrift.jar, which in turn uses log4j. So I can't simply remove log4j. Moreover - the compiler doesn't complain of inexisting libs (I believe because they are not used in the code), but proguard does

Comment: I see. Still, does this affect the runtime behavior of the application at all (Proguard may not be able to fully optimize the code, though)?

Comment: It doesn't create apk at all. Just writes BUILD FAILED
/home/stoned/android-sdk-linux_86/tools/ant/main_rules.xml:430: Please correct the above warnings first.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, just added

```
-dontwarn
-dontnote
```

to proguard.cfg

Comment: You are suggesting to not warn/note on anything anymore. That's probably not what you want.