# AdColony proguard error

Tags: android, proguard, ads, adcolony

I include `AdColony` in my android app and now I am trying to export my app with proguard. I found configuration for `AdColony` [here](https://github.com/AdColony/AdColony-Android-SDK/wiki) and [here](https://wiki.operamediaworks.com/display/AMS/Integrating+with+AdColony). I tried to include them separately and together into proguard.cfg, but it doesn't work.

Configurations:

```
-dontwarn android.webkit.**
# another config
-dontwarn com.jirbo.adcolony.**
-keep class com.jirbo.adcolony.**{*;}
```

Proguard says:

```
Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
Proguard Error 1 
Output: 
Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation: 
Class       = [com/immersion/hapticmediasdk/HapticContentSDK] 
Method      = [bБ04110411Б04110411()I] 
Exception   = [java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException] (-1) 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 
at     proguard.optimize.peephole.BranchTargetFinder.visitConstantInstruction(BranchTargetFinder.java:492) 
at proguard.classfile.instruction.ConstantInstruction.accept(ConstantInstruction.java:157) 
at proguard.classfile.attribute.CodeAttribute.instructionsAccept(CodeAttribute.java:138) 
at proguard.classfile.attribute.CodeAttribute.instructionsAccept(CodeAttribute.java:110) 
at proguard.optimize.peephole.BranchTargetFinder.visitCodeAttribute(BranchTargetFinder.java:354) 
at proguard.classfile.attribute.CodeAttribute.accept(CodeAttribute.java:101) 
at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.visitCodeAttribute0(PartialEvaluator.java:261) 
at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.visitCodeAttribute(PartialEvaluator.java:181) 
at proguard.optimize.info.ParameterUsageMarker.visitCodeAttribute(ParameterUsageMarker.java:176) 
at proguard.classfile.attribute.CodeAttribute.accept(CodeAttribute.java:101) 
at proguard.classfile.ProgramMethod.attributesAccept(ProgramMethod.java:79) 
at proguard.optimize.info.ParameterUsageMarker.visitProgramMethod(ParameterUsageMarker.java:136) 
at proguard.optimize.OptimizationInfoMemberFilter.visitProgramMethod(OptimizationInfoMemberFilter.java:81) 
at proguard.classfile.ProgramMethod.accept(ProgramMethod.java:71) 
at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.methodsAccept(ProgramClass.java:504) 
at proguard.classfile.visitor.AllMethodVisitor.visitProgramClass(AllMethodVisitor.java:47) 
at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.accept(ProgramClass.java:346) 
at proguard.classfile.ClassPool.classesAccept(ClassPool.java:116) 
at proguard.optimize.Optimizer.execute(Optimizer.java:341) 
at proguard.ProGuard.optimize(ProGuard.java:306) 
at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:115) 
at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

My proguard.cfg file:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525661/android-proguard-cant-find-dynamically-referenced-class-javax-swing
-dontwarn java.awt.**
-dontnote java.awt.**
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.**


-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# Google Play Billing
-keep class com.android.vending.billing.**


-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
    public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepnames class com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput*
-keepclassmembers class com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput* {<init>(...);}

#GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES
-keep class com.google.** { *;}
-keep interface com.google.** { *;}
-dontwarn com.google.**

-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe
-dontwarn com.google.common.collect.MinMaxPriorityQueue
-keepattributes *Annotation*,Signature
-keep class * extends com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson {*;}
-keep class com.google.api.services.drive.** {*;}

# AdColony
-dontwarn android.webkit.**
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So what do you see on the console?

Comment: @tomsv, I see the text below the line **Proguard says:**

Comment: @Nolesh Can replace them with the following: -keepnames class com.jirbo.adcolony.** { *; }

Comment: @AlexiosKarapetsas, if I do this I get the following: `Warning: com.jirbo.adcolony.ae: can't find referenced method 'void evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String,android.webkit.ValueCallback)' in class android.webkit.WebView ` in console

Comment: @Nolesh I was meaning to replace the 2 lines with the adcolony. And keep the webkit as is

Comment: @AlexiosKarapetsas, I did `-dontwarn android.webkit.**
-keepnames class com.jirbo.adcolony.** { *; }` and got the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like the solution I found by myself, but it's better than nothing. In the current moment I am using **version 2.2.2**. I began to test earlier versions of this library and found out that **version 2.1.3** works as appropriate. Now my app is exported successfully. Sometimes, improvements lead to the generation of new bugs.