# jar file problem in android

Tags: android, jar

i am trying to design an app on the basis of a java project according to that java project it has lot of jar files. when i tried converting the code's to an android i don't get much error but when i added the jar files used in that java net beans projects, there is no error but in the console it shows as "Dalvik errror......"

When i searched through google i found one of them saying remove the jar file. How to solve my problem please help me friends.....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the answers in ["Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" on external JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar)   are not satisfactory its better to remove the unwanted jar file. It will remove all the errors immediately

Answer (score 0):

Right-click your project in Eclipse, click Properties.  Go to Java Build Path and then click the Libraries tab.  You should have "Android " and "android.jar".  Delete "android.jar".