# Proguard ParseException with Default proguard.cfg on Android

Tags: android, proguard

I am about to release an application but, while i was building it using Export Tool of Android SDK in Eclipse, i get the error below.

- I didn't change the proguard.cfg.
- It is in the root folder of my project.
- I only add `proguard.config=proguard.cfg` to default.properties.

I read the forum and update proguard (just copied the files to the tools folder of Android SDK), but still I doesn't work. I couldn't figure out what the problem is with the 'Projects\Eclipse' ??

If you help me, I will be so glad...

```
[2011-08-08 02:32:46 - CoolProject] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2011-08-08 02:32:46 - CoolProject] proguard.ParseException: Unknown option 'Projects\Eclipse' in argument number 9
[2011-08-08 02:32:46 - CoolProject]     at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parse(ConfigurationParser.java:172)
[2011-08-08 02:32:46 - CoolProject]     at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:484)
```

Comment: Hey Osman I am having the same problem i searched a lot but still didn't  find any useful steps / method which can help me out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah that is right, but also I did something that I didn't know :)

My solution was:

1. I updated to latest Android SDK.
2. I changed SDK path property under Eclipse: Window > Preferences > Android > SDK Location as something like c:\Progra~1\android-sdk. The Progra~1 can be used for writing Program Files witout spaces. You can use `DIR /X` command in command prompt on Windows to get no space versions of Paths.
3. I moved my Eclipse Workspace to a location without spaces like D:\
4. The changes above didn't enough to solve the problem. I got "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" error dialog witout any explanation on output console. Then I found [that topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar) and did what [that reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar/7004730#7004730) says.

Then it worked ;)

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate x86. I hope it works for others too.
Arda.

Comment: very good. renaming the path so that it doesn't contain any nlanks helped in my case.

Comment: Hey Osman I am having the same problem i searched a lot but still didn't  find any useful steps / method which can help me out.

Answer (score 2):

Your project path probably contains a space. This should be [fixed](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16674) in the latest version of the Android SDK (at least for the Ant build). Otherwise, you should use a path without spaces for the time being.