# Proguard ParseException unknown option dump.txt

Tags: android, proguard, parseexception

I read alot of posts similar to this topic, but cant solve it anyway.
Everytime I try to export my signed application with the obfuscator enabled, I get the following:

```
[2011-12-23 13:26:35 - AppName] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2011-12-23 13:26:35 - AppName] proguard.ParseException: Unknown option 'android\AppName\proguard\dump.txt' in argument number 9
[2011-12-23 13:26:35 - AppName]     at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parse(ConfigurationParser.java:170)
[2011-12-23 13:26:35 - AppName]     at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:491)
```

I use the Google APIs Version 2.3.3 and the standard configuration and just added the `proguard.config=proguard.cfg` to the `projects.properties.` 
I use "Progra~1" in the SDK path and tried clean already.

As far as I know, the dump.txt is generated in a successfully run of the obfuscator.

Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Ok its been a space in my workspace folder. @Warren: dunno what arg nr 9 is - made no sense for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the space in the project folder path. There is a duplicate question here [Proguard ParseException with Default proguard.cfg on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976625/proguard-parseexception-with-default-proguard-cfg-on-android) and the answer is step 2,3,4 and 5 of the accepted answer.