# Error when exporting Android APK with LibGDX and ProGuard

Tags: android, eclipse, libgdx, apk, proguard

I’m trying to export an Android APK with Proguard and I’m getting this error:

```
[2015-05-06 19:29:31 - Metronome-android] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2015-05-06 19:29:31 - Metronome-android] proguard.ParseException: Unknown option '(' in argument number 14
[2015-05-06 19:29:31 - Metronome-android]   at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parse(ConfigurationParser.java:191)
[2015-05-06 19:29:31 - Metronome-android]   at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:484)
```

The config file mentioned here already exists in my Android project folder, which is named “proguard-project.txt”.
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/ProGuard-DexGuard-and-libGDX

And in the project.properties file I uncommented the line specified in the comments to enable ProGuard and resaved the file:

```
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

I'm using Eclipse and to export the APK, I right-clicked the Android project and selected: Android Tools --> Export Signed Application Package
Then I went through the process to export it. When I clicked “Finish” I got the error mentioned above.

I have been able to successfully run ProGuard on a desktop application but I can't get the Android APK to work, any ideas what I’m doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it's help . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976625/proguard-parseexception-with-default-proguard-cfg-on-android]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following notes:

- Check this link [Proguard Error: Unknown option '(' in argument number 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546191/proguard-error-unknown-option-in-argument-number-12)
- Check this link [Proguard ParseException unknown option dump.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616123/proguard-parseexception-unknown-option-dump-txt)
- If your project using some external library you must add some prograud configurations in the progaurd file.
- Be careful of the syntax in the proguard file content.