# Proguard Error: Unknown option '(' in argument number 12

Tags: android, proguard

I can't export my project with proguard, I get this error and out of solutions..
I don't know where is this argument number 12 ...

```
[2013-05-14 17:38:39 - LiveWallpaper] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2013-05-14 17:38:39 - LiveWallpaper] Error: Unknown option '(' in argument number 12
```

my project.properties:

```
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
proguard.config=proguard.cfg

# Project target.
target=android-13
```

and my proguard.cfg is empty.

Thanks!

Comment: Error: Unknown option '0409' in argument number 1

Answer (score 3):

Ok so I found the solution using
[Proguard ParseException with Default proguard.cfg on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976625/proguard-parseexception-with-default-proguard-cfg-on-android)

My problem was the my workplace directory folder name was with a "(" character .. so I moved it to another directory without whitespaces or "(" and it solved it.