# error when exporting. apk

Tags: android

killed 3 hours for this error. Search the forums did not give (anything you want)
compiles on the emulator well. but for export if the problem

```
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexException: Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:663)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ExportHelper.exportReleaseApk(ExportHelper.java:204)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ExportHelper$2.run(ExportHelper.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

help those who faced

Comment: Are you using proguard? External JARs?

Comment: Have you tried the answers from here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar

Comment: I using proguard, jar not using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to **update** proguard, and the issue is resolved

Answer (score 4):

It happened to me once while using proguard and I was able to solve using -forceprocessing in proguard.cfg

Answer (score 0):

This answer is pretty much everywhere:
If you're on Eclipse go to Project >> Clean... >> Check your project, OK.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an error in eclipse have you tried to do Project -> clean?
Perhaps restart Eclipse, adb and then try it again.