# Samsung Tab Emulator in Eclipse

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

i downloaded a tab emulator from http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/down/cnts/toolSDK.detail.view.do?cntsId=9500&platformId=1
and have added it to my android-sdk. i am able to create an AVD but unable to set the build target of my project to this tab. when i try to run the application on the tab AVD, i get the following error:
 Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: wrapper was not properly loaded first

Comment: first clean your project.............

Comment: yes tried that also, wont work

Comment: Check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try restarting your Eclipse and start your emulator again. It should work.