# How can download map in osmdroid?

Tags: android, osmdroid

All I have used osmdroid and i want to download map zip files from android app and than create offline map. Any one have more knowledge about osmdroid and offline map and navigation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easisest way is to download [MOBAC](http://mobac.sourceforge.net/), then run it and mark out an area you want, store the tiles in Osmdroid.zip format. When that's done, drop the zip file into the osmdroid folder on your device.

Comment: i want download this zip file from my android app programatically. Is it possible?

Comment: But the map tiles downloaded by MOBAC do not allow routing.

Comment: also MOBAC is probably going to be blocked because it causes heavy traffic for OSM servers.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to download [Mobile Atlas Creator](http://mobac.sourceforge.net/). This link is for [the latest version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mobac/files/Mobile%20Atlas%20Creator/MOBAC%201.9/Mobile%20Atlas%20Creator%201.9.16.zip/download) of MOBAC

1- In Mobile Atlas Creator select your area of interest.

2- Select your Map Source

3- Select Zoom Levels

4- Add Selection

5- Create Atlas

[image: Mobac]

6- After downloading is finished move the zip-file to `/mnt/sdcard/osmdroid/` on your device.

You can find more details about next steps [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32163885/2101822)

Comment: Note that MOBAC is very bad for OSM tile servers and you are likely getting blocked. See https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/MOBAC for more information.

Comment: @scai Yes, You are right. It was OK when I answered this question. ;)

Comment: @scai  then what is better?

Comment: @kemdo Rendering your own tiles, e.g. with [Maperitive](http://maperitive.net/) (or a [full tile server](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/), which is much more work and probably unneeded for most users).

Comment: Hello. I got mess mono quit unexpectedly. when run mono Maperitive.exe, dont know why but i can run maperitive :(. 

......I follow on http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Maperitive#Mac_OS_X