# Displaying shape file or and OSM file in android as a map

Tags: java, android, osmdroid, shapefile, openstreetmap

I want to implement a Indoor Navigation application in android.
My first task is to display the map in android.

I have created the indoor map in both shape file and OSM file format.

• I created the shape file using QGIS.
• I created the OSM file using JOSM.

I couldn't find any guideline on how to display any of those file types in android platform as a map.

I have found the FootPath indoor navigation app which uses an OSM map tiles for the map.
I found this question in Stack exchange about performing a similar task

[How to create map tiles from OpenStreetMap offline, display it on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625620/how-to-create-map-tiles-from-openstreetmap-offline-display-it-on-android)

But the answer of this question doesn't help me on creating the Map.Perticularly the part where i have to create tiles using mobile atlas creator.I have posted a comment on that question to clarify that.

I want to know whether there are any other way i could do this?

Can any one help me with this? 
Thank YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try mapforge.
You can find it here [mapforge](https://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/)