# How to use OSM map in an android application.? Is there any tutorial to learn about using OSM in android.?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I am searching for a tutorial/manual or steps to include Open street map into my android application. All I found is either a big project with lot more functionality on it, otherwise so many questions ended without proper conclusion about "HOW"..!

Is there any proper blog/site or document that can a fresher can refer?

Comment: As you aren't talking about how/what aspects of OSM data you want to include, I can just point you to this point, which isn't a tutorial but a general overview:  
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Frameworks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't know of any tutorials but here's the code I wrote for a minimal example using Osmdroid.

```
// This is all you need to display an OSM map using osmdroid
package osmdemo.demo;

import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.TileSourceFactory;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapController;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class OsmdroidDemoMap extends Activity {
    private MapView         mMapView;
    private MapController   mMapController;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.osm_main);
        mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mMapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.DEFAULT_TILE_SOURCE);
        mMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mMapController = (MapController) mMapView.getController();
        mMapController.setZoom(13);
        GeoPoint gPt = new GeoPoint(51500000, -150000);
        mMapController.setCenter(gPt);
    }
}
/* HAVE THIS AS YOUR osm_main.xml
---------------------------------------------------------- XML START
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true" />
</LinearLayout>
---------------------------------------------------------- XML END
Include slf4j-android-1.5.8.jar and osmdroid-android-4.1.jar in the build path
(Google search for where to get them from)
*/
```

Note that you must now use the latest version (4.1) to avoid getting blocked from downloading tiles from OSM.

Also note that they are moving their repositries to Github and the process isn't complete yet. This page [downloads](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/wiki/Downloads) holds the links for the jars

Comment: When I execute the app, all I get is an empty grid. There's a zoom in/out button, but it just zooms in and out on the grid. Can it be that OpenStreetMaps.org requires you to incorporate an API-key into the app, for it to be able to retrieve tiles?

Answer (score 7):

[This OSMdroid sample project](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-use-the-osmdroid-library) is definitely the simplest that i have come across.  No more than 5 minutes to be up and running.  Pay attention to the manifest file.

For a bit more complexity, [this tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.com.br/2012/05/display-current-location-marker-on.html) displays a map with a current geopoint.

[Here are some snippets](http://www.javased.com/?api=org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint) from various projects.  Haven't tested all of them, though.

You should download [OSMdroid](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/org/osmdroid/osmdroid-android/) and [SLF4J](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/slf4j-android.htm), place in `libs` folder, `Add as Library` osmdroid, fix AndroidManifest.xml with proper permissions (see first tutorial).  If you do this, there is no need to alter `gradle.build` file as recommended in first tutorial.

I recommend that you use, for starters, the older versions of osmdroid (3.x) when using these.  Once you are comfortable, migrate to newer version of osmdroid (4.x or 5.x).

GeoPoint and MapController classes change names in newer versions, so watch out for [INCOMPATIBLE TYPES ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36742161/1166727)

> IGeoPoint cannot be converted to GeoPoint
>
> IMapController cannot be converted to MapController

Answer (score 4):

I have explained the steps [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32164125/2101822).
I also recommend you take a look at their [Sample Project](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/tree/master/OpenStreetMapViewer) which is very useful. And their documentation about [HOW](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-use-the-osmdroid-library) ;)

And for **Offline Use**

1-  you must download the map using [MOBAC](http://mobac.sourceforge.net/).

2- Place it into `/mnt/sdcard/osmdroid/`

After these steps everything is the same as @Nick explained.

Comment: What format should the offline maps be in when downloading using MOBAC?

Answer (score 4):

One mistake that people using Google Maps like service make is that they treat OpenStreetMap as just map tile provider. You need to know that OpenStreetMap is actually a big free editable wiki geodatabase and there are three different ways you can use this database.

1. You can make tools to write to this database. There is REST Api https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6 . This is what you use if you have to make changes to the database. This is the least common use case but is most thoroughly documented. The API is main OSM API and can be used to download data as well but it is not the recommended way to download OSM data.
2. Next you can read data from this database. The best way to do is to download planet extracts https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm and smaller extracts hosted by geofabrik http://download.geofabrik.de/. If you want to make more specific queries, best options could be Overpass API https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API.
3. Finally there are a range of service that are built on top of OSM data like (map tiles, routing, POI search, geocoding). This is most probably what you are looking for there are lot of options for this. For Android a good complete solution is Mapbox https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/map-sdk/overview/ . The great thing about mapbox android sdk is that they provide everything like map tiles, routing, POI search, geocoding, offline maps and even live traffic using one service. Also you can follow the above link and look at tutorials and sample code. One bad thing is that you will need to use mapbox service and there is a risk of vendor lock in, but most of mapbox products are open source. If you work a little hard you should be able to piece together other solutions for yourself as well.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

OSM is really great but hard to use specially with it's google api and also there isn't much tutorials and docs for it, the best option will be using services like [mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com)
which have great docs and a lot of sources, easy to use and affordable. hope this will help.