# OSMDROID: error: incompatible types: IGeoPoint cannot be converted to GeoPoint

Tags: android, osmdroid

I am building a sample OSMdroid app mixing and matching from various sources.

In using [this sample code](http://android-er.blogspot.com.br/2012/05/display-current-location-marker-on.html),

```
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
...
 private void setOverlayLoc(Location overlayloc){
   GeoPoint overlocGeoPoint = new GeoPoint(overlayloc);
  //---
     overlayItemArray.clear();

     OverlayItem newMyLocationItem = new OverlayItem(
       "My Location", "My Location", overlocGeoPoint);
     overlayItemArray.add(newMyLocationItem);
  }
...
   @Override
   public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapview, boolean arg2) {
...
     //overlayItemArray have only ONE element only, so I hard code to get(0)
     GeoPoint in = overlayItemArray.get(0).getPoint();
```

I started receiving the following error (in reference to the last line above):

> error: incompatible types: IGeoPoint cannot be
>   converted to GeoPoint

I am using Android Studio 2.0, osmdroid 4.3, slf4j 1.6.1

The error message makes very little sense to me, since i did not declare or import said `IGeoPoint` class.  Any suggestions as to how to go about this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

OverlayItem.getPoint() returns a IGeoPoint, and Projection.toPixels() needs a IGeoPoint. So :

```
IGeoPoint in = overlayItemArray.get(0).getPoint();

mapview.getProjection().toPixels(in, out);
```

(and don't go back to an older version, but upgrade to the latest one!)

Comment: wasnt explicitely dealing with projections.  lemme check this angle.  UPVOTED! :)

Answer (score 1):

Workaround: Change the osmdroid version from 4.3 to 3.0.x.  `IGeoPoint` class does not exist in 3.0.x, but in 4.3 it does.

NOTE: version 4.2 has the same problem with `IMapController`

Solution: Change declaration to `private IGeoPoint startPoint;` and the same for `IMapController` and my code became compatible with versions 4.3+ .

Answer (score -2):

```
import org.osmdroid.api.IMapController;


private IMapController myMapController;
```