# Android programming offline google maps

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm making an application with google maps (or maps at least) and i've a problem. I want it to work offline. Though I cant find how to do that with google maps.

1 - What other sdk can I use to replace it? Any tutorial how to implement it?

Also, using this post, I need to define the limit of zoom in the application (I mean, it can only go from 16-18). How can I do that?

Thanks for you time!

Comment: That is two questions. The zoom levels can be limited like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818016/google-maps-v3-limit-viewable-area-and-zoom-level. Tutorials recommendations are off topic, but it is certainly very doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, that's against Google's terms of service, so I wouldn't bother trying to devise a solution.

OpenStreetMap is probably better suited to this, simply because is open, so you are mostly free to do what you want with it. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625620/how-to-create-map-tiles-from-openstreetmap-offline-display-it-on-android) should get you started.