# Offline Open Street Map in Android

Tags: android, openstreetmap, android-maps

I have a project that has a requirement of displaying map data in offline mode also. I have used OpenStreet maps. I have downloaded .PBF file for my area . I want to access these map file from android application. I also visit these links:
[How to create map tiles from OpenStreetMap offline, display it on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625620/how-to-create-map-tiles-from-openstreetmap-offline-display-it-on-android)
[PBF Format](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PBF_Format)
I am a newbie in Android developing so excuse me about my elementary question. Can anybody guide me how I use .PBF file and solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use a library that supports offline OSM maps, for example mapsforge or the Mapbox Android SDK. For more information consult the OSM wiki about [offline OSM](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Offline_Openstreetmap) and [Android libraries](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android#Libraries_for_developers).

Comment: could you please show me a simple code that access simple open street map?

Comment: That depends on the library you want to use. So far your use-case is very unspecific, i.e. whether you also need features like geocoding and routing. Also, these libraries usually have better code examples than I can offer.

Comment: it's not open sourced (Mapbox)