# How to find Bonjour in local wifi in Android

Tags: android, bonjour, jmdns

I have a problem that I want to get an Ip of remote computer via Bonjour which is preinstalled . But I unable to connect with that, I don't know why because I have download an example code from Git Hub and also download the jmdns3.4.1 Jar. But the sample contains the error as *Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1*. Then I have written this question to get the exact answer.

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 0):

First off you need to use a special version of jmdns compiled for Android found [here](https://github.com/twitwi/AndroidDnssdDemo). The reason is [Android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29) cannot actually execute Java class files, but rather executes Java dex files since it [uses](http://source.android.com/tech/dalvik/index.html) [Dalvik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29).

It may also be a jar-conflict if you are 100% sure you're using the right jar-file. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar) for more information.