# Proguard android error

Tags: android, proguard

I followed [these](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html) instructions and performed [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar/7004730#7004730) modifications.

When i try to export my application with the default proguard.cfg config i get this error

> [2011-11-01 20:32:18 - ] Proguard returned with error code 1. See
>   console [2011-11-01 20:32:18 - ] java.io.IOException: Can't read
>   [C:\Program
>   Files\Android\android-sdk-windows\add-ons\addon_google_apis_google_inc_13\libs\usb.jar]
>   (No such file or directory) [2011-11-01 20:32:18 - ]  at
>   proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:230) [2011-11-01
>   20:32:18 - ]  at
>   proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:200) [2011-11-01
>   20:32:18 - ]  at
>   proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:178) [2011-11-01
>   20:32:18 - ]  at
>   proguard.InputReader.execute(InputReader.java:100) [2011-11-01
>   20:32:18 - ]  at proguard.ProGuard.readInput(ProGuard.java:196)
>   [2011-11-01 20:32:18 - ]  at
>   proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:78) [2011-11-01 20:32:18 -
>   ]     at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)

i cannot understand why usb.jar is asked. Anyone know something about it?

I use proguard 4.6 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`usb.jar` is present in my install (`addon_google_apis_google_inc_13/libs`, on Linux) and it is also listed in `addon_google_apis_google_inc_13/manifest.ini`. Presumably, the build process therefore adds it to the class path (irrespective of the ProGuard version or configuration). ProGuard complains if any jars in the specified class path are missing. You should check where the jar has gone.

Comment: i ended up downloading is and placed it where it asked it. Hmm broken API13 install?

Comment: Proguard is a mess.  I tried to use ProGuard on the jackson json library and it was a complete disaster. According to Jackson, they make use of dynamic linking, but Proguard was like "Dude where are these classes."  Even after I found every single jar it was complaining about, it would crash when I actually used the compiled app.