# Please explain this error message

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1” on external Jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar)

I get this error:

> [2011-12-13 14:21:19 - Timer Code] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

Can you please explain this? Thank you.

Comment: In what context do you recieve the error? Could you isolate a section of code causing your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project » Properties » Java Build Path » Libraries and remove all except the "Android X.Y" (in my case Android 2.1). click OK. Go to Project » Clean » Clean projects selected below » select your project and click OK. That should work.

Comment: or follow up the below link,, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar

Answer (score 0):

*clean your project and rebuild it when you are getting this exception*

Have a look on [Reason of Conversion to dalvik format failed with error](http://bimbim.in/post/2010/09/24/Reason-of-Conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1.aspx)