# How can resolve a Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1?

Tags: android, exception, dalvik, dx

I am working on inbuild email application in this application. I am getting error logs in building time. How can I resolve this issue?

```
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx 
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dx.util.ExceptionWithContext: bitIndex < 0: -1
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.util.ExceptionWithContext.withContext(ExceptionWithContext.java:46)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:344)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:134)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.java:87)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:483)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:455)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:394)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:418)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:329)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:206)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:179)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:729)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(PostCompilerBuilder.java:602)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:728)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:321)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:396)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:618)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:597)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:124)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ProjectHelper.build(ProjectHelper.java:869)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:146)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:854)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:703)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:928)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1132)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: bitIndex < 0: -1
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at java.util.BitSet.set(Unknown Source)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaMethod.bitSetFromLabelList(SsaMethod.java:141)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaBasicBlock.newFromRop(SsaBasicBlock.java:162)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaMethod.convertRopToSsaBlocks(SsaMethod.java:174)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaMethod.newFromRopMethod(SsaMethod.java:104)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaConverter.convertToSsaMethod(SsaConverter.java:45)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.ssa.Optimizer.optimize(Optimizer.java:99)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.ssa.Optimizer.optimize(Optimizer.java:73)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:273)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  ... 35 more
...while processing close ()V
...while processing android/media/AmrInputStream.class

[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx 
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/android/server/ResettableTimeout$T;
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:163)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:486)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:455)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:394)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:418)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:329)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:206)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:179)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:729)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(PostCompilerBuilder.java:602)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:728)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:321)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:396)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:618)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:597)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:124)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ProjectHelper.build(ProjectHelper.java:869)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:146)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:854)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:703)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:928)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1132)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx 
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/android/server/ResettableTimeout$T;
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:163)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:486)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:455)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:394)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:418)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:329)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:206)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:179)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:729)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(PostCompilerBuilder.java:602)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:728)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:321)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:396)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:618)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:597)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:124)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ProjectHelper.build(ProjectHelper.java:869)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:146)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:854)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:703)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:928)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1132)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Dx 3 errors; aborting
[2012-01-02 10:53:07 - AndroidMail] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to `Project` » `Properties` » `Java Build Path` » `Libraries` and remove all except your android SDK version click OK. Go to `Project` » `Clean` » `Clean projects selected below` » `select your project and click OK` I hope this will help.

Another reason is that it can be a JAR file conflict, if you have a JAR file located somewhere in your project folder and then added it as a Java Path Library. It does not show up under the Package Explorer, so you don't notice it, but it does get counted twice, causing the dreaded Dalvik error

Comment: I agree - this definitely sounds like a .jar file conflict, or using a .jar that's incompatible with Android.  This scenario also occurred here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar

Comment: If your issue is resolved by my answer then kindly accept it :)

Comment: [2012-01-02 13:38:47 - AndroidMail] Dx 
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dx.util.ExceptionWithContext: bitIndex < 0: -1
[2012-01-02 13:38:47 - AndroidMail] Dx  at com.android.dx.util.ExceptionWithContext.withContext(ExceptionWithContext.java:46) how can resolve this issue

Comment: This is mainly because of the jar file itself. Maybe its not imported as a library / dependency, but is present still in the source path.Check this this

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the maintainers of Android's dx tool; this is a dx crash and it's our fault that you're seeing this exception.

I've triaged it to my own team as [bug 23821](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23821). We'll have much better luck fixing the bug if you can provide detailed steps to reproduce the crash. Providing us with links to the input .class or .java files that trigger the crash would be best. It's possible that your .class files are invalid; even if that is the case dx should report a friendlier error.

Please attach instructions to reproduce and related files to the bug!

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is the fault that you need a package called dx.

My solution to your problem is to use windos xp sp 3. Download ADT 23 and solve this problem.

**Link package dx.jar** -> http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/d/Downloaddxjar.htm