# Android: CSS Error when using HTML Unit & Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, htmlunit

I am using Html Unit to go to a webpage, fill in some forms, and click a button to get to the next webpage. That new webpage, (called newPage in my code) is what I'm extracting the html source from.

**This method works perfectly in Netbeans (although it does give an excessive amount of warnings)**

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

/* Regular (textview, button, etc) imports */

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.Page;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlAnchor;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSubmitInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTextInput;


        String username = "USERNAME", school = "SCHOOL", userpassword = "PASSWORD";
        HtmlElement loginName = null;
        HtmlElement password = null;
        //HtmlPage newPage;
        HtmlAnchor anchorByHref = null;
        try {
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            final HtmlPage page = webClient
                    .getPage("https://cupertino.schoolloop.com/portal/login?d=x&return_url=1325402408153");
            loginName = page.getElementByName("login_name");
            password = page.getElementByName("password");
            loginName.setTextContent(username);
            loginName.setAttribute("value", username);
            password.setAttribute("value", userpassword);
            password.setTextContent(userpassword);
            anchorByHref = page
                    .getAnchorByHref("javascript:document.form.event_override.value='login';document.form.submit();");
            HtmlPage newPage = anchorByHref.click();

            webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
            String html = newPage.getWebResponse().getContentAsString();


            message2.setText(html);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }


}
```

However, in Eclipse running Android, it says

```
01-02 17:38:54.099: E/dalvikvm(23163): Could not find class 'org.w3c.dom.css.CSSCharsetRule', referenced from method com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.CSSCharsetRule.getCharsetRule
```

in the logcat.

Also, **it doesn't set message2's text as the html I want** although when I try this in Netbeans and print "html" it does in fact print the full html source of the page!

In summary, there are 2 Problems. Eclipse is not successfully getting the html, and it is giving an error saying could not find CSSCharsetRule class. I think I have imported the appropriate .jar for this, but I am not certain because HTML Unit comes with around 15 .jars and I cannot import them all otherwise the application has trouble in emulator and phone.

```
I have figured out that the error was due to not importing xml-apis-1.3.04.jar (which was imported in the Netbeans Project).
```

However, now I encounter a

> "Conversion to Dalvik Format Failed with Error 1"

Error.

Is it possible that any of the problems would cause the Null value of html, and how do I fix the Dalvik Conversion Error?

***.jar Eclipse(too many makes app heavy, and including xml-apis causes Dalvik Error)***
[image]

***Jar files in Netbeans (working)***
[image]

Comment: import meaning to add them to the build path in Eclipse*. Also, adding JUnit as one of the jars helped.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a problem with you classpath within eclipse:

```
Could not find class 'org.w3c.dom.css.CSSCharsetRule'
```

Do you have all Jars included to the buildpath?

```
Conversion to Dalvik Format Failed with Error 1
```

This tells me, that one of your *.class can't be convertet into a *dex-file

Maybe you have two jar-files with the same class inside:

> I solved the problem.
>
> It seems that I have two jars on my buildpath that include the same
>   package and classes.

["Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" on external JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar)

**edit**
To find duplicate Classes, extract all jars with your favourite unzip-tool and wait for "This file aready exists".

Comment: How do I figure out which .jar files conflict? Also, do you think this is the reason why html variable would return null? (No content there)

again, if I import *all* jars in Netbeans, it works. If I import all jars in Eclipse, the application becomes too heavy. 

I have edited my answer with pictures of the jars imported in each IDE if that will help.

Comment: also, I think the addition of the xml-apis jar is what *has* the class 'org.w3c.dom.css.CSSCharsetRule' but that is what causes the Dalvik Error.

Comment: Thanks for the JARS, please expand the eclipse ADT and Android ClassPath Container. Maybe you have duplicated APIs there.

Comment: I do not think those are the conflicting jars as I said, the Dalvik Error occurs when I add xml-apis.jar. I will try unzipping them and let you know.