# Proguard and Dalvik error code 1

Tags: android, android-manifest, proguard

I've been having a problem with obfuscating my code using ProGuard. I've tried all the suggestions on the other, similar questions on here and still it doesn't work.

Essentially, here are all the facts I can glean from the situation:

- My libraries are set up so that ViewPagerIndicator is referenced by ActionBarSherlock, which in turn is referenced by FormulaeLib which is referenced by the app, FormulaePro.
- trying to use ant also fails, with errors at `<sdk_dir>/tools/ant/build.xml` lines 485, 602 and 622
- commenting out the proguard configuration in project.properties will give a successful build.
- I'm using ProGuard 4.7

UPDATES:

- I've now traced this problem back to my CursorLoader implementation. I've had so many problems with this, I have now just gone back to using the (deprecated) managedQuery(..) method of loading cursors.

The end of the console output:

```
[2012-01-06 17:45:07 - FormulaePro] applyFileOverlay for mipmap
<lots of "new resource id" things>
[2012-01-06 17:45:43 - FormulaePro]     (new resource id view from D:\Dropbox\Android\FormulaeLib\res\menu\view.xml)
[2012-01-06 17:45:43 - FormulaePro]   Writing symbols for class R.
[2012-01-06 17:45:43 - FormulaePro]   Writing symbols for class R.
[2012-01-06 17:45:43 - FormulaePro]   Writing symbols for class R.
[2012-01-06 17:45:43 - FormulaePro]   Writing symbols for class R.
[2012-01-06 17:45:45 - FormulaePro] Starting full Package build.
[2012-01-06 17:45:45 - FormulaePro] Skipping over Post Compiler.
```

So, can someone much cleverer than me figure out what the heck is going on?

Comment: clarification..above description sounds like you are attempting to chain android project libraries, which you cannot do as of yet..is this correct read of what you have?

Answer (score 6):

Have you recently upgraded to SDK Tools rev 14 or higher?

I am not cleverer than you are, but the problem you are describing reminds me of [my recent awful experience with Dalvik error 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828255/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-why).

If this is the case, try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8106366/1124861) from the amazing @TheTerribleSwiftTomato:

1. In your app project, check for any linked source folders pointing to your library projects (they have names in the form "LibraryName_src").
2. Select all those projects, right-click, choose "Build Path"->"Remove from Build Path".
3. Choose "Also unlink the folder from the project", and click "Yes".
4. Clean, rebuild and redeploy the project.

**Update:** Another scenario I recently encountered: You renamed one of the classes. In that case, the files generated in the `proguard` folder (dump.txt, mapping.txt, seeds.txt, usage.ext) may not reflect that change. In that case, **delete all 4** of them. They will automatically generated next time you use the `File > Export` - this time not generating the dreaded "Dalvik error 1".

Good luck!

Comment: thanks, I tried these but it didn't work :( found methods of getting it to work (above), but they don't really help, they make any more sense to you?

Comment: @Espiandev Sorry, I haven't experience yet what you described. My applications have been comprised of a single (own) activity only so far.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the points refered by @Bill The Ape, have you upgraded your proguard files after updating the SDK?

That can be the problem, check out here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7386541/327011

Comment: thanks for the help, but I have upgraded and doesn't seem to make much help. I've found some new stuff through testing, maybe that will shed some more light?

Answer (score 1):

I recently had an error with proguard after updating the Android SDK... I kept getting an "Error 1" issue as well.  What fixed it for me was downloading the latest proguard binaries and replacing the ones that came with the Android SDK.

Hopefully this helps for all of you as well...

http://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/files/

Answer (score 0):

Please Remove library & Once again Configure build path then the Dalvik Virtual Machine Error will be removed.

Try to Fix properties to 1.6 Compiler Once again.

Try it will resolve your issue!!!

Answer (score 0):

i also got same problem when i upgraded to ADT 16 yesterday. To solve problem I removed ADT 16 and installed ADT 15.

Try this. This might solve your problem