# Trying to use KSoap jar in Android project and it at compilation

Tags: android, ksoap

I am trying to use KSoap library in android project to work with webservices and i fail from the very beggining. I import [this jar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kxml/files/latest/download?source=files) and add it in build path. All seems ok but when i build the project i get this error(there were others similar to this, when using different versions of ksoap):

```
[2012-01-17 13:22:27 - TestWSApp] Dx 
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/ksoap2/transport/AndroidHttpTransport;
at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:163)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:486)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:455)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:394)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:418)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:329)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:206)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:179)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:745)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(PostCompilerBuilder.java:634)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:728)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:321)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:396)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:618)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:597)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:124)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ProjectHelper.doFullIncrementalDebugBuild(ProjectHelper.java:961)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:146)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:854)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:703)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:928)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1132)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

[2012-01-17 14:06:52 - ShapeSalesForceApp] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2012-01-17 14:06:52 - ShapeSalesForceApp] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

There were some articles saying i have to rebuild the maven project and create a new jar because there are some mistakes.

I just hope somebody knows a good working version for ksoap. Should it matter the jdk version i use? i think not..but now i am trying to find out the root of the problem and then the solution. can you help please? thx anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your download points to KXML use the KSoap2 library:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ksoap2/files/ksoap2/2.1.2/ksoap2-j2me-core-2.1.2.jar/download

or add the source directly to your project. This is more complicated but it lets more flexibility if you have to customize:

http://ksoap2.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ksoap2/tags/RELEASE_2_0_2/ksoap2/ksoap2/src/

Comment: I did what you suggested(first option) and now i get this error: `UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/kobjects/base64/Base64;
 at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)`

Comment: You must clean your project before adding the new library. If this dosent work maybe there is another conflicting jar in your project. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar

Comment: i cannot believe i spent almost a day on this, but only after deleting the project and placing the code back again the errors stopped appeared...
don't understand.