# New Eclipse & Android Install - Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, dalvik

I have just installed a brand new copy of Eclipse and Android SDK. Yet when I try to run a simple Android program I get the error:
*"Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1"*

I have tried all the solutions from "Cleaning the Project", modifying "proguard.bat", even upgrading from Proguard 4.4 to 4.7 yet none of those solutions work.

Any ideas?

This is really disappointing!

**NOTE**
- Using Eclipse 3.7.1 on XP

Answer (score 1):

I've gotten this error when I've had a library linked more than once. Right click on your project and go to Build Path -> Configure Build Path. Check the libraries tab and make sure you aren't importing the same library twice. When I switched to 4.0.3 Eclipse decided to import the Android libraries twice giving me this error.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Eclipse are you running?

I have had this problem few times myself, usually the solutions you tried work for me, however there is an indepth discussion about the error in this topic.

["Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" on external JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar)

One of those solutions should solve the problem