# Dalvik format failed error in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1” on external JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar)

I am getting following Error while running my program
`Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1.` So what could be the problem ?

Comment: when your getting this error?

Comment: You probably find answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must have included new libraries(jar files) into your project, which is causing the error you stated. The error is caused if two or more libraries added have the same class.  You should find the libraries which are causing the error and try removing one of them.

Comment: Welcome to [SO], please avoid the use of slang abbreviations. u = you etc.