# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError - Why? How to troubleshoot?

Tags: android, android-intent, noclassdeffounderror, android-activity

One of my menu items in my application simply tries to invoke another activity (that belongs to a different project in the same workspace):

```
myActivity.startActivity(new Intent(myActivity, com.bill.the.App.class));
```

But that immediately results in an exception at runtime:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(3847): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.bill.the.App
```

Why?

What am I missing?

(the project compiles and build just fine, it's only at run time that this error occurs)

Comment: do you have that second project (which you are trying to invoke by menu) already installed on your target/emulator at the moment when you launch your activity? Perhaps, the project (hence the classes in it) is not installed so the class can't be found.

Comment: @alex.veprik Yes, I have that second project installed (with the same package name as in this workspace but a different package name from the invoking application's). But... that installed second project was built on a different workspace. Does that matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be that the project or library containing com.bill.the.App is included in compilation search path, but not included in the resulting apk file (that is deployed to the device). If you include the project or library containing com.bill.the.App using a wrong way, this can happen. Make sure that you include it by using Android Library Project (project properties -> Android) or by including the jar file in the project properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries.

Comment: I did reference it as a Library project in the calling application, but I didn't mark it as `IsLibrary` in its own properties because it can be a standalone application. I am now checking another direction: It is being called from a Library project, so perhaps the Library's manifest should include that `<activity android:name=".App"/>` and not only the application's manifest. +1 for now.

Comment: Nope. Even adding the `<activity android:name=".App"/>` to the Library project didn't help. This is getting weird.

Comment: Well, I played a little with those `project properties -> Android` settings (**Is Library** checkbox *and* the **Add Library** button), got some `Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1` but I quickly solved it thanks to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8106366/1124861). Exception solved.

Answer (score 3):

Just Open your `AndroidManiFest.xml`, and write following line in it before the `</application>` tag.

```
<activity android:name=".App"/>
```

Comment: That didn't help, but I think that this is a necessary tip on the way to solving the problem (see my comment to @Rich). +1.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when importing an old Eclipse/ADT project (made of several projects AKA modules) to Android Studio (2021.3.1.17).

The solution was to right-click the app's module > `Open Module Settings` > `Dependencies` > (app's module) > `+` (Add Dependency) > `3 Module Dependency` > Select the module/project that contains the missing class.

Answer (score 0):

The activity may not be registered in the manifest

Comment: In the manifest of the **invoking** application? If so, then you are right. It's not registered in the manifest. Let me check if registering it solves the problem...

Comment: Hmmm... I just tried that and it doesn't solve the problem. I actually added the `<activity android:name="com.bill.the.App"></activity>` just before the `</application>` tag in the manifest of the invoking application and I am still getting this error. +1 Nevertheless.