# Error while run web service

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-emulator

I'm trying to do web service using android. I created the web service using visual studio. I tested the web service manually and it return me value. Now, i try to configure the webservice in android so it can return the same value but an error was occured when i try to run the code. **Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1**.
Need advice from the gurus. Thanks

Below is my code.

```
package com.test.web;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class WebSrviceActivity extends Activity {
    private final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://smartposter.smartag.my";
    private final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://smartposter.smartag.my/SmartPosterV1.asmx";
    private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://smartposter.smartag.my/HelloWorld";
    private final String METHOD_NAME = "HelloWorld";
    private static final String URL = "http://localhost:62558/SmartPosterV1.asmx";
    private Object resultsRequestSOAP = null;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        setContentView(tv);


    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);


     //SoapObject
    /*request.addProperty("firstname", "John");
    request.addProperty("lastname", "Williams");*/
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);


    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try
    {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        resultsRequestSOAP =  envelope.getResponse();
        String[] results = (String[])  resultsRequestSOAP;
        tv.setText( results[0]);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "testig"+results[0].toString(),    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }

    }
}
```

Comment: you are right. once i removed the jar. its working fine. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on previous answers it seems that you have clashing libraries in your project:

["Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" on external JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar)

Answer (score 0):

cannot use soap on android

you can try other

maybe ksoap