# Latest ADT updates (2012-03-21) break my Android projects

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

Anyone know what's borked in the v17 ADT updates?

I tried many of the fixes here (issue ["Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" on external JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar)) but to no avail, nothing compiles. I keep getting errors in the console about "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1".

I eventually restored everything from backups taken last night but would like to know how to update my (Linux) system to v17 cleanly. Anyone have better luck with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a follow up - I finally got this working. Part of my problem was in the way I was using library projects. I have an Eclipse library project (mainapp) which incorporates the android facebook sdk (fblib) as a library. I then have a third project (newapp) which uses mainapp as a library.  "chaining" these projects together as libraries needs to be done differently at each level I guess. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356866/unable-to-build-eclipse-library-projects-after-adt-update) for more info.

```
fblib (library)         
     \                 
      \               
      mainapp (library)
                     \
                      \
                       newapp (final application)
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to remove libraries from Build Path.
Full instruction here: [Fix (some) problems with libraries in the ADT 17 Plugin](http://xrigau.wordpress.com/2012/03/22/fix-some-problems-with-libraries-in-the-adt-17-plugin-10/)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same thing.  If you've followed the instructions for [enter link description here](http://xrigau.wordpress.com/2012/03/22/fix-some-problems-with-libraries-in-the-adt-17-plugin-10/) and are still getting that error like I was, do a clean on all of your projects--I had set them up correctly, but needed to do a clean yet.

Comment: I updated and did indeed try some of the links showing how to fix the problem but was unable to fix it. I have a library project which includes another library so wasn't clear how to configure that for the "adt 17" way. I restored everything from backup and will need to try again some other time. deadlines this week....