# Android Sdk tools Revision 22 issue?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-sdk-tools

I just updated the SDK tools in Eclipse to revision 22, and since then I cannot build my project. Specifically the R class is not recognized in my Activity (I was getting compiler errors) and even when I imported manually, again the import was not working.

Additionally the project `gen` folder is empty, and cleaning the project/workspace (having `build automatically` option on) didn't make any difference.

Is this a known issue? Did it happen to everyone? Is there a workaround? Maybe Google just wants us to switch to Android platform the soonest possible?

Comment: Which IDE did you us?, just updated sdk tools, after did the check for updates on eclipse, installed the new ones all is working fine. Eclipse Juno

Comment: You can find some help [Here][1]. Thanks.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16900308/1021653

Comment: I wonder if this is google's passive agressive attempt to get people to use Android Studio instead of eclipse... This problem doesn't happen anywhere else and is very undocumented for a breaking change...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I had major issues with the update as well. In my case my project uses a library that also depends on another library. I found that I needed to check the box for `Android Private Libraries` in the `order/export` tab of the Java Build Path for the project - and each of my connected libraries -- to properly compile and run the app on a device.

Some others have indicated that you need to also check `Android Dependencies` too but that doesn't seem necessary for my project.

Comment: Thanks a lot... I was including a jar. The project was building ok, but whenever I tried to run the application I was getting a class not defined exception for a class that was included in the specific jar. Adding the jar in the export path was the solution.

Comment: Had the same problem. Had to update twice per Rany's suggestion and then also import/export as listed here.

Comment: Also had this problem, 4 hours of time wasted due to this!

Comment: Strange that the checkboxes need to be checked in all libraries and app projects, but that did in fact fix things for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

Yes it's right.
I had the problem too, there is a new "Android SDK Bild-tools". Open the Android SDK Manager and make a update, maybe twice.

[image]

More info:https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/rCaeT3qckoE%5B1-25-false%5D

Comment: Eventually after updating I managed to make my project build, but I had problems with a library that I was using (comment in the accepted answer).

Comment: In the SDK manager, you can force an update by going to 'packages' menu item and clicking 'reload'

Comment: This fixed everything for me. I wish I could give you more than one votes. Thanks man! :D

Answer (score 8):

I had this same issue.

In the project properties, Java Build Path, Order and Export section, I had to make sure the Android Private Libraries was checked.

Then I had to clean the project. After that it seems to work.

> It was indeed an issue with 'Order and Export' of the Java Build Path.
>
> When upgrading, the 'Order and Export' of the new 'Android Private Libraries' is not always checked. And the android-support-v4.jar is now in this 'Android Private Libraries' section.
>
> To fix this, go to 'Order and Export' and check 'Android Private Libraries'. Then refresh/clean/rebuild.
>
> After you done this 'fix' for a library project, you may need to just close and re-open any depending project, because they may not see this 'fix' immediately.

I found the answer [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/adt-dev/epOfZbKPFdk).

Comment: I needed to reload the SDK manager to ensure all the tools packages were updated, reload the Android SDK Tooks, fix the "Order and Export" problem, and then reboot eclipse.

But it works now, thank you this notes and the associated link helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Same error i am also having,
After i delete the empty gen folder it created automatically with files like R.java and all error has gone working fine

Answer (score 0):

I am on windows 7, I had the same problem and merely making eclipse to "Run as administrator" and installing the packages again worked for me. (I had to do it even though I was logged in as an admin)