# Updating to Android SDK Tools R22

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I updated the SDK Tools to R22 and the ADT Plugin as well. Everything worked well before the update but since then, I have problems.

Basically I have 2 library projects and an app project. One of my library projects contains some jar files in the "libs" folder. One of these jars is used in the app project itself for some initial setup. Before the update, everything worked fine, but now it asks me to add the jar to the build path and even if I do so, when running the app it still gives me ClassNotFoundException.

Did anyone had some similar experience or has any idea about what causes this and how can it be fixed?

Thanks.

Comment: Anybody open a bug for google?

Comment: Please note that tags stand alone.  Combining `android`, `sdk` and `tools` does not mean the same thing as the tag `android-sdk-tools`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check this [Android Sdk tools Revision 22 issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583786/android-sdk-tools-revision-22-issue). "I found that I needed to check all of the boxes in the order/export tab of the Java Build Path for the project - and each library -- to properly compile and run the app on a device." - should helps.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55304) worked for me

Answer (score 0):

OK. I also had a Simillar kind of Problem.

Like say If you have library project as `google-play-services_lib` before updating than might happen that your library code has been also updated after updating your SDK.

> You Should Remove that library project from your Workspace and Import
>   again from the source
>   folder like in my case i had to import from `/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib`. Add reference of 
>   your library path to you android app project. clean and build your Project.

Hope this Helps.

Comment: I have a JAR for urban airship's push notifications that currently causes the issue. I have tried deleting the library and app projects and import them to a completely new workspace, but it didn't solved my problem.

Comment: @LeviKurti : Make Sure you have that jar file in libs folder and you have reference it correctly in your project.

Comment: Also tried that. I've deleted the whole libs folder, re-created it and added the jars again, but still no luck. I've been reading a lot of posts with issues after updating to r22 but didn't found a solution for my problem yet.

Answer (score 0):

you should try to upgrade eclipse.

1) Get the new imports via the Android SDK Manager
2) Check for updates in the Eclipse repository: help/check for updates

That would "for real" upgrade the SDK version in your configs.

Dunno if the other steps pointed by VShcryabets are needed, i had them before.