# ClassNotFoundException is thrown by all Android projects that used some sort of library after ADT plugin Update

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, android-sdk-tools

I am using Eclipse. I am facing this issue Right after **GOOGLE IO 2013** when i updated my **ADT plugin, Android SDK tools to Revision 22 and Android SDK platform-tools to revision 17**

All of my projects that previously worked have started throwing **ClassNotFoundException** after this  update for no reason. I have searched stackoverflow but none of the answers seem to solve my problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating to Android SDK Tools R22](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586909/updating-to-android-sdk-tools-r22) **and** http://stackoverflow.com/q/16583786/450534

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i have Solved this issue and i thought of sharing it with everyone.

I have noticed that there is a new Android Package named as **Android Private Libraries** and after hours of trying i found a way to fix this.

Right Click on your **Project** then

Goto **Build Path-> Configure Build Path -> Order and Export**

when you are there you should **check** the **Android Private Libraries** and then click OK button.

if you still face the problem delete all the files inside your bin folder and rebuilt you project.

Hope this helps others who are facing the same problem as me

Comment: But how to get `Android Private Libraries` inside my Android Project ??

Comment: @Kedarnath Its already there please update ur ADT version to latest one.

Comment: Yes,I just find it out.

Answer (score 6):

Faced the same problem when i updated the adt
try this

In Eclipse go to:

"Project" -> "Properties" -> "Java Build Properties"

On the "Order and Export" tab I checked "Android Private Libraries" on my project. I also did this for the library project it references. This fixed my class not found errors following upgrading to SDK 22.