# Android -- include jar cause 'class not found' exception

Tags: android, eclipse, settings, installation

I want to include Netty's jar into my android project.

I've tried [adding it directly as a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project), but I'm getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`, pointing to a class from Netty.

Another way is to put the library directly into the `libs` folder, and when I'm doing so, the Eclipse's Android plugin would automatically include the jars in the `libs` folder into the 'android private library'. In that case it seems that I cannot attach a source.

I tried deleting the android private library, and link everything through the reference library. It seems that the android cannot find class from reference library; because it's causing the `NoClassDefFoundError` exception.

I want to know if there're proper ways to solve this problem.

NOTE: I do know that there're lots of posts about this issue.. such as this method (from the link above):

1. **Create a folder called `libs`** in your project's root folder
2. Copy your **JAR files to the `libs` folder**
3. Now **right click on the Jar file and then select Build Path > Add to Build
   Path**, which will create a folder called 'Referenced Libraries' within your
   project

But it's just causing the `NoClassDefFoundError` exception.

I'm using Eclipse Kepler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved such issue with the next steps:

1. Go to **Java Build Path**->**Order And Export**
2. Turn on check box for all libraries
3. Click OK
4. Clean and Rebuild your project

Comment: This solution almost solve my problem, one step need to add is you have to clean and rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't **check** the **Android Private Libraries**. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642868/classnotfoundexception-is-thrown-by-all-android-projects-that-used-some-sort-of/16642869#16642869) answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to run Project → Clean(select all projects). It should clean & rebuild everything.

If eclipse haven't imported jar you will have errors in your java files. If your projects are building with no errors and even is trying to start on emulator or device it may be problem of compilatiion. This problem happens often when using gradle. And the best solution is to clean everything and rebuild :)

Answer (score 0):

Above all steps give you same kind of error again and again. Don't be afraid I will solve your problem:

1. Instead of adding external `.jar` file, remove it from library.
2. Copy your driver file into project **web-inf/lib(ex.ojdbc14.jar)**
3. Run your dyanamic application.