# android sdk corrupted after again intalling the New Software in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-adt

I have a trouble. My Eclipse and Android sdk was running fine and developing apps. I actually installed the "New Software" again without any reason i.e. **Eclipse -> Install New Software ->** (Android SDK + https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/)
Now all the previously developed apps gives errors ( mostly R can't be found). Someone can guide me please, what to do now so that I can save my time and code
Regards,

Comment: Check if some of these answers help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583786/android-sdk-tools-revision-22-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution is:**

Open Android sdk manager and

> Install Android SDK Build Tools

thats it