# Can't find "this" class NoClassDefFoundError - Android

Tags: java, android, facebook, reference, noclassdeffounderror

I'm trying very simply to test the 3.0 Facebook get started guide. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

I have had some problems with imports and references but I don't know it that's relevant. The issue I'm having is when I try to run the test Activity ant get this error:

```
Could not find class 'com.test1.test2.FacebookLogin$1', referenced from method com.test1.test2.FacebookLogin.onCreate
```

Code:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_facebook_login);


        //Error occurs here when I use 'this'
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

          // callback when session changes state
          @Override
          public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
              if (session.isOpened()) {

                // make request to the /me API
                  Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                    // callback after Graph API response with user object
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        if (user != null) {
                              TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                              welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
                            }

                    }
                  });

              }
          }
        });
    }
```

How can I get a `NoClassDefFoundError` when I use `this`?

**UPDATE:**

After testing with the Scrumtious tutorial https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/authenticate/ as well I'm getting the same error when I call the `Session.StatusCallback()` method. I still don't know what my problem is though.

Thanks for the help

Comment: May this help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678630/noclassdeffounderror-android

Comment: It seems like you are also using `super` and not just `this`

Comment: @ZouZou Thanks but no I did not

Comment: FacebookLogin$1 means it is annonymous class in facebooklogin, maybe  Session.StatusCallback? is it part of facebook api? do you uploading it to your android device?

Comment: @user902383 Yes that seems to be some of the issue. I tried with the Scrumptious test app now and getting the same error when new Session.StatusCallback() is called, do you ave any clue what it could be, and yes I upload it to my device. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you updated to Android sdk tools revision 22. There is an issue there. You have to add the libraries you use in the export path. Check:
[Android Sdk tools Revision 22 issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583786/android-sdk-tools-revision-22-issue)