# Project can't find a reference to a type in a library imported in the library that this project imports

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

I have a project A that imports a library. Name it library1. A is built as a library too. Then I have another project B that imports A and uses a type in library1. This was working for me until I updated to api 22. Now eclipse claims that can't find the type in library1.

I have spent quite a few hours trying to fix the problem without luck. Could anyone suggest what is hapenning?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583786/android-sdk-tools-revision-22-issue). There is a known issue with r22 tools. In short you have to include the libraries you use, in your export path.

Comment: What an odd issue. This fixed the problem. Thanks. The problem I'm facing now is that I get an class not found exception when using any class from the library :/