# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo 9

Tags: android

I have a problem that I'm dealing with since a couple of days, I tried a lot but i don`t find the solution.

Any help would be much appreciated!

MainActivity

```
         package de.ok.locmarker;

            import android.app.Dialog;
            import android.content.ContentValues;
            import android.net.Uri;
            import android.os.AsyncTask;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
            import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
            import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
            import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
            import android.view.Menu;
            import android.widget.Toast;


            import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
            import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
            import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
            import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
            import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener;
            import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
            import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
            import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

            public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

            GoogleMap googleMap;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                // Getting Google Play availability status
                int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

                // Showing status
                if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

                    int requestCode = 10;
                    Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
                    dialog.show();

                }else { // Google Play Services are available

                    // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
                    SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

                    // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
                    googleMap = fm.getMap();

                    // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
                    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                    // Invoke LoaderCallbacks to retrieve and draw already saved locations in map
                    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
                }

                googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

                        // Drawing marker on the map
                        drawMarker(point);

                        // Creating an instance of ContentValues
                        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

                        // Setting latitude in ContentValues
                        contentValues.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_LAT, point.latitude );

                        // Setting longitude in ContentValues
                        contentValues.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_LNG, point.longitude);

                        // Setting zoom in ContentValues
                        contentValues.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_ZOOM, googleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom);

                        // Creating an instance of LocationInsertTask
                        LocationInsertTask insertTask = new LocationInsertTask();

                        // Storing the latitude, longitude and zoom level to SQLite database
                        insertTask.execute(contentValues);

                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Marker is added to the Map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                googleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new OnMapLongClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {

                        // Removing all markers from the Google Map
                        googleMap.clear();

                        // Creating an instance of LocationDeleteTask
                        LocationDeleteTask deleteTask = new LocationDeleteTask();

                        // Deleting all the rows from SQLite database table
                        deleteTask.execute();

                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "All markers are removed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            private void drawMarker(LatLng point){
                // Creating an instance of MarkerOptions
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

                // Setting latitude and longitude for the marker
                markerOptions.position(point);

                // Adding marker on the Google Map
                googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            }

            private class LocationInsertTask extends AsyncTask<ContentValues, Void, Void>{
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(ContentValues... contentValues) {

                    /** Setting up values to insert the clicked location into SQLite database */
                    getContentResolver().insert(LocationsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, contentValues[0]);
                    return null;
                }
            }

            private class LocationDeleteTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                    /** Deleting all the locations stored in SQLite database */
                    getContentResolver().delete(LocationsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null);
                    return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0,
                Bundle arg1) {

                // Uri to the content provider LocationsContentProvider
                Uri uri = LocationsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI;

                // Fetches all the rows from locations table
                return new CursorLoader(this, uri, null, null, null, null);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0,
                Cursor arg1) {
                int locationCount = 0;
                double lat=0;
                double lng=0;
                float zoom=0;

                // Number of locations available in the SQLite database table
                locationCount = arg1.getCount();

                // Move the current record pointer to the first row of the table
                arg1.moveToFirst();

                for(int i=0;i<locationCount;i++){

                    // Get the latitude
                    lat = arg1.getDouble(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_LAT));

                    // Get the longitude
                    lng = arg1.getDouble(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_LNG));

                    // Get the zoom level
                    zoom = arg1.getFloat(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_ZOOM));

                    // Creating an instance of LatLng to plot the location in Google Maps
                    LatLng location = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                    // Drawing the marker in the Google Maps
                    drawMarker(location);

                    // Traverse the pointer to the next row
                    arg1.moveToNext();
                }

                if(locationCount>0){
                    // Moving CameraPosition to last clicked position
                    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(lat,lng)));

                    // Setting the zoom level in the map on last position  is clicked
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(zoom));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
            }
```

Manifest.xml

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            package="de.ok.locmarker"
            android:versionCode="1"
            android:versionName="1.0" >

            <uses-sdk
                android:minSdkVersion="14"
                android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

            <permission
                android:name="de.ok.locmarker.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
                android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

            <uses-permission android:name="de.ok.locmarker.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

            <uses-feature
                android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
                android:required="true"/>

            <application
                android:allowBackup="true"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
                <activity
                    android:name=".LocMarker"
                    android:label="@string/app_name" >
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>


                <provider
                    android:name="LocationsContentProvider"
                    android:authorities="de.ok.locmarker.locations"
                    android:exported="false" />

                <meta-data
                    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                    android:value="xxx" />
            </application>
        </manifest>
```

activity_main

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

LogCat

```
 06-07 01:28:37.365: E/AndroidRuntime(5664): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   06-07 01:28:37.365: E/AndroidRuntime(5664):
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
   ComponentInfo{de.ok.locmarker/de.ok.locmarker.LocMarker}:
   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.ok.locmarker.LocMarker 06-07
   01:28:37.365: E/AndroidRuntime(5664):    at
   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2016)
   06-07 01:28:37.365: E/AndroidRuntime(5664):  at
   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
   06-07 01:28:37.365: E/AndroidRuntime(5664):  at
   android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134) 06-07
   01:28:37.365: E/AndroidRuntime(5664):    at
   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
   06-07 01:28:37.365: E/AndroidRuntime(5664):  at
   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 06-07
   01:28:37.365: E/AndroidRuntime(5664):    at
   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity
    android:name=".LocMarker"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The activty name should be `.MainActivty` instead of `.LocMarker`.

Answer (score 0):

If this happens when you upgraded to Android SDK Tools revision 22, check out this answer:

[Android Sdk tools Revision 22 issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583786/android-sdk-tools-revision-22-issue)