# Unexpected screen comes up For SSO Android

Tags: facebook, single-sign-on

I followed the tutorial here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#sso
and managed to implement SSO. I had to run everything without adding a reference to the Facebook.apk from GitHub because it would cause a "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" otherwise. So everything runs fine except that when i go to the log in screen instead of getting an Application log in page, I get a general facebook log-in page. Is this because i don't have that reference? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be better off trying to get rid of the "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" problem.  See [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2680827/223837) for a list of possible causes and tutorials.

Comment: Hey thanks for answering. I managed to get rid of the error. The same problem is still happening. When I first start up my app the log-in screen for the "official facebook app" shows up, rather than the facebook log-in in screen for my app.