# Android SDK r18 export release error

Tags: android

I've 2 Android projects in workspace; first is libray project and other is application that refers to first project. Clean and Build is fine without any error. But when I try to export release build it gives error: "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1"

Please, help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
Removed r18 and went for r17 and then every thing is fine.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION 1:**

Are you using proguard? if so.. you might want to replace the one in the sdk (C:\android-sdk\tools2\proguard*) with the latest version from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/files/proguard/).

You can rename the old proguard to proguard2 and place the downloaded version in C:\android-sdk\tools2\proguard*

*Note: the folder of your AndroidSDK might be different

---

**SOLUTION 2:**

If you had imported other projects as libraries for the main project you might check if those libraries are imported twice:

[image: Android Libraries]
[image: Android Build Path]

Those Images were extracted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9357378/571353)

---

**SOLUTION 3:**

Create a new Android project with the same package name, copy all your resources, Manifest and source files, configure the external libraries and then try to compile the new project

Comment: I'm not using proguard. Also, haven't imported libraries twice. When I referenced library project, then in Android Dependencies > jar of library project + jar in library projects libs folder + annotations.jar (refered by library project from android-sdk-windows\tools\support) is automatically shown. I've refered no other library in main project.

Comment: See my new solution to see if that works.. That solved the problem for me a couple of times.

Comment: Had already done as you have suggested in new solution, without any luck.

Comment: Then I suggest you to start "removing" classes until you find if any of those are causing the problem..

Answer (score 1):

That usually happens when you have `android.jar` accidentally included twice.  Go into your project's `Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries` and remove the one that's not under the `Android X.Y` drop-down.

Comment: In both projects android.jar is shown in Android 2.2 reference only. There is no 2 references of it. in both projects.