# Resolve this error in Android Eclipse

Tags: android

When i'm executing my project its giving me and error

> ### Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

i'm unable to find what is the error and how to resolve it

Comment: Anything you've changed recently? Have you tried restarting the IDE, emulator, and every related app?

Comment: You can try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that you have conflicting class/method names. Try to find which of your libraries/.jar files could have the same method names/ classes and make sure you only have no duplicates in a project scope.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the external JAR's you added, and add only those required again. That will solve the issue!

Answer (score 1):

Remove from the libs> jars from the project...It will be resolve...