# simple android activity sending sms error "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1"

Tags: android, sms

Iv'e been working with some code that will send a sms message and when i run it i get an error:

[2012-04-22 01:01:00 - SMS_Experiment] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2012-04-22 01:01:00 - SMS_Experiment] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

```
   import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.net.Uri;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.View;
   import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.Toast;

   public class SMS_ExperimentActivity extends Activity {

Button buttonSend;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
       final String phoneNumber="**********";
       buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
               try {
                 startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:"+ phoneNumber + "?body=Hello%20WORLD" )));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "SMS faild, please try again later!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
      });
       }
       }
```

and the main.xml looks like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonSend"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Send" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Comment: added permission in manifeast file?

Comment: I added the android.permission.SEND_SMS permission...are there any other i should add?

Comment: once close your emulator and reopen it also clean your project once

Comment: would you like me to post the manifest file?

Comment: ok i will close emulator and reopen

Comment: no just clean your project and try

Comment: well it turned out that an emulator was never opened to begin with so i restarted my eclipse and tried to run the project again and I still get the same error...

Comment: i cleaned the project and ran it again...still getting the same error

Comment: hey you dont have oncreate method at all

Comment: its ok lastly paste your manifeast file too

Comment: the manifest file is posted.......

Comment: sorry looks every thing is ok. try to run it on 2.2 instead of 4.0.3

Comment: will do..... give me second...ill tell you what happened...

Comment: YES SUCCESS!!! THAT WAS IT!!!! THank You Agarwal!!!  The emulator came up but i did not see the app...so i  connected it to my phone and no more error.....guess 4.0.3 did not like what the code example..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the modified code:::

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class SMS_ExperimentActivity extends Activity {
    @overide
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nameoflayout);
        buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
       final String phoneNumber="**********";
       buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
               try {
                 startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:"+ phoneNumber)));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "SMS faild, please try again later!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
      });
       }
       }
```

Comment: Please don't add new answers every time you change something. Edit your original answer to add/update new information.

Comment: do you have any external jar added

Comment: Go to Project » Properties » Java Build Path » Libraries and remove all except the "Android X.Y" (in my case Android 1.5). click OK. Go to Project » Clean » Clean projects selected below » select your project and click OK. That should work.

Comment: i have three listings in my Libraries .....1.android.jar-Users/codenamejpiterx/android-sdks/platfroms//android-10  .....2.Android 4.0.3     ...........3.com.android.ide.eclipse.ide.LIBRARIES   .......which two should i get rid of?????

Comment: can you share screen shot of it

Comment: i took a screen shot of it how do i let you see it?

Answer (score 0):

Please see this thread "[Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar)" on external Jar

more information here: Reason of [Conversion to dalvik format failed with error 1](http://bimbim.in/post/2010/09/24/Reason-of-Conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1.aspx)