# Unfortunately android application is stopped

Tags: android

```
05-10 22:12:43.572: E/dalvikvm(566): Could not find class 'com.commonsware.cwac.merge.MergeAdapter', referenced from method FXPAL.Unity.Android.UnityMain.updateView
05-10 22:12:43.862: E/dalvikvm(566): Could not find class 'com.xtify.android.sdk.PersistentLocationManager', referenced from method FXPAL.Unity.Android.ReportingService.onCreate
05-10 22:12:44.182: E/AndroidRuntime(566): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-10 22:12:44.182: E/AndroidRuntime(566): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.xtify.android.sdk.PersistentLocationManager
05-10 22:12:44.182: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at FXPAL.Unity.Android.ReportingService.onCreate(ReportingService.java:240)
05-10 22:12:44.182: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2253)
05-10 22:12:44.182: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-10 22:12:44.182: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1201)
05-10 22:12:44.182: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-10 22:12:44.182: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-10 22:12:44.182: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-10 22:12:44.182: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-10 22:12:44.182: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-10 22:12:44.182: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-10 22:12:44.182: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-10 22:12:44.182: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-10 22:12:55.702: E/dalvikvm(589): Could not find class 'com.xtify.android.sdk.PersistentLocationManager', referenced from method FXPAL.Unity.Android.ReportingService.onCreate
05-10 22:12:55.992: E/AndroidRuntime(589): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-10 22:12:55.992: E/AndroidRuntime(589): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.xtify.android.sdk.PersistentLocationManager
05-10 22:12:55.992: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at FXPAL.Unity.Android.ReportingService.onCreate(ReportingService.java:240)
05-10 22:12:55.992: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2253)
05-10 22:12:55.992: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-10 22:12:55.992: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1201)
05-10 22:12:55.992: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-10 22:12:55.992: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-10 22:12:55.992: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-10 22:12:55.992: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-10 22:12:55.992: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-10 22:12:55.992: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-10 22:12:55.992: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-10 22:12:55.992: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-10 22:13:01.262: E/dalvikvm(605): Could not find class 'com.commonsware.cwac.merge.MergeAdapter', referenced from method FXPAL.Unity.Android.UnityMain.updateView
05-10 22:13:01.502: E/dalvikvm(605): Could not find class 'com.xtify.android.sdk.PersistentLocationManager', referenced from method FXPAL.Unity.Android.ReportingService.onCreate
05-10 22:13:01.722: E/AndroidRuntime(605): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-10 22:13:01.722: E/AndroidRuntime(605): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.xtify.android.sdk.PersistentLocationManager
05-10 22:13:01.722: E/AndroidRuntime(605):  at FXPAL.Unity.Android.ReportingService.onCreate(ReportingService.java:240)
05-10 22:13:01.722: E/AndroidRuntime(605):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2253)
05-10 22:13:01.722: E/AndroidRuntime(605):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-10 22:13:01.722: E/AndroidRuntime(605):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1201)
05-10 22:13:01.722: E/AndroidRuntime(605):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-10 22:13:01.722: E/AndroidRuntime(605):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-10 22:13:01.722: E/AndroidRuntime(605):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-10 22:13:01.722: E/AndroidRuntime(605):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-10 22:13:01.722: E/AndroidRuntime(605):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-10 22:13:01.722: E/AndroidRuntime(605):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-10 22:13:01.722: E/AndroidRuntime(605):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-10 22:13:01.722: E/AndroidRuntime(605):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am new to android development.I am upgrading an android application from 2.2 Android to 4.0.3. The application is not starting and saying "Unfortunately **myUnity** application has stopped", but previously the application was good.The above is the error log i am getting while I debug the application.I am also pasting my manifest file below. Please help me out guys as I am facing this problem since many days.
Thanks in advance.

Android manifest file is


      
    
    
        
            
                
                
            
            
                
                
            
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
            
                
                
            
        
        
            
                
                
                
            
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
            
                
                
                
            
        
        
            
                 -->

Thanks in advance.... i am also new to stackflow... i am really sorry if I posted the question in wrong format.

Regards,
Rakesh.

---

**LogCat**
05-15 06:52:35.898: E/dalvikvm(1436): Could not find class 'com.commonsware.cwac.merge.MergeAdapter', referenced from method FXPAL.Unity.Android.UnityMain.updateView
05-15 06:52:36.187: E/dalvikvm(1436): Could not find class 'com.xtify.android.sdk.PersistentLocationManager', referenced from method FXPAL.Unity.Android.ReportingService.onCreate

The above is my logcat. Looking forward to your help guyz. The below is my android Manifest

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I had made changes in my Android Environment. I was using some external libraries (JARs) and I was also getting this "NoClassDef" error. I made a folder by name of "libs" copied the libraries into it. Right clicked on "libs" then buildpath -> add as source folder.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. But it didnt work. Now the error i am getting is Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now I am able to solve most of my errors. But I still have 2 more errors. I am pasting it now.

Comment: 05-15 06:52:35.898: E/dalvikvm(1436): Could not find class 'com.commonsware.cwac.merge.MergeAdapter', referenced from method FXPAL.Unity.Android.UnityMain.updateView
05-15 06:52:36.187: E/dalvikvm(1436): Could not find class 'com.xtify.android.sdk.PersistentLocationManager', referenced from method FXPAL.Unity.Android.ReportingService.onCreate

Comment: at this point i dont know but we can follow the above steps that I have told (add the libs folder), from the libraries from build-path just remove "android dependencies", "clean" the project (Project->clean) and run it. Best of luck

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is `

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.xtify.android.sdk.PersistentLocationManager
```

`

Copied from documentation:

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to
>   load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or
>   as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no
>   definition of the class could be found. The searched-for class
>   definition existed when the currently executing class was compiled,
>   but the definition can no longer be found.

Reason of NoClassDefFoundError is that a particular class is not available in Classpath, so u need to add that into Classpath. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

No apologies needed, posting the logcat is the right thing to do. The first line says "Could not find class 'com.commonsware.cwac.merge.MergeAdapter', referenced from method FXPAL.Unity.Android.UnityMain.updateView". Be sure you are still linking that package into your app.

BTW, I can't see your manifest file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I will attach the manifest file now.