# Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 adt r18

Tags: android, adt, actionbarsherlock, acra

although there are many questions with a similar title, I could not find the solution to this issue.

I have an Android project in Eclipse which references ActionBarSherlock 4.0.2 as Android library. In addition, I have added the JARs for ACRA and Google Analytics in the /libs folder. The support v4 jar is taken from ABS libs.

The project's Java Build Path looks like this
[image]

When exporting through the wizard I get the "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" error.

Cleaning, removing all Android Dependencies and clicking on Fix Project Properties and cleaning does all not work.

Any idea?

**EDIT:**

I missed some info: I'm doing this on Mac OS 10.6.8, Eclipse Indigo, Android SDK Tools r19 and ADT plugin v18.

project.properties file includes the proguard.cfg file: commenting it does avoid the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2680827/741249?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, actually there are many questions here regarding the Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 error. The one you linked referes to Android 1.6 and older stuff, so it might be another issue. Moreover, I tried possibly all answers of that question and none worked. This question should refer to the current versions of Eclipse, Android SDK and ADT plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to overcome the issue, here soem details if they can be of use to anybody:

I first tried everything from clean to close/reopen project etc etc etc

I finally too the latest beta of proguard [from http://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/files/](http://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/files/) and replaced the /lib folder in android-sdk-macosx/tools/proguard with the one from the beta version (proguard4.8beta1) and .. it works!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after updating to ADT 20 (released with Jelly Bean), and similarly, all the old solutions (clean, rebuild, etc.) didn't help. Taking a clue from omoling's answer, I updated my Flurry jar to the latest from their website... and the problem cleared up.

So, if you're having this problem, try updating any/all external libraries that your project uses.