# Android Dx Error1, Failed to convert to Dalvik format

Tags: java, android, dalvik

I'm getting desperate with this Problem: I want to export/run my Android Application with one additional `.jar` I added to the buildpath. I'm sure I added it correctly, there are 5 other .jars included and they all work fine.

with this special one I get the mentioned error.
I've already tried everything that can be found in this question:
["Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" on external JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar)

and several other links google spat out. The main Problem is, I actually do not understand what the message I appended want's to tell me because if I add all the jars to a "normal" javaproject, it runs perfectly fine...

> Developing on Android 4.0.3,
>
> proguard 4.8,
>
> adt 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534,
>
> eclipse 3.7.1.r37

please help me

> [2012-07-18 10:45:48 - myapp] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner
> class (iaik.xml.crypto.XSecProvider$1) that doesn't come with an
> associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced
> by a compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The
> recommended solution is to recompile the class from source, using an
> up-to-date compiler and without specifying any "-target" type options.
> The consequence of ignoring this warning is that reflective operations
> on this class will incorrectly indicate that it is *not* an inner
> class.
>
> ...
> ...
>
> [2012-07-18 10:45:48 - myapp] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner
> class (iaik.xml.crypto.XSecProvider$2) that doesn't come with an
> associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced
> by a compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The
> recommended solution is to recompile the class from source, using an
> up-to-date compiler and without specifying any "-target" type options.
> The consequence of ignoring this warning is that reflective operations
> on this class will incorrectly indicate that it is *not* an inner
> class.
>
> Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*) when
> not building a core library.
>
> This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file in
> your application's project, when using an IDE (such as Eclipse). If
> you are sure you're not intentionally defining a core class, then this
> is the most likely explanation of what's going on.
>
> However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
> namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example, from a
> non-Android virtual machine project. This will most assuredly not
> work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the compatibility of your app with
> future versions of the platform. It is also often of questionable
> legality.
>
> If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
> appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine distribution,
> as opposed to compiling an application -- then use the
> "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
>
> If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact building an
> application, then be forewarned that your application will still fail
> to build or run, at some point. Please be prepared for angry customers
> who find, for example, that your application ceases to function once
> they upgrade their operating system. You will be to blame for this
> problem.
>
> If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a core
> package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to repackage
> that code. That is, move the classes in question into your own package
> namespace. This means that they will never be in conflict with core
> system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help you in this endeavor.
> If you find that you cannot do this, then that is an indication that
> the path you are on will ultimately lead to pain, suffering, grief,
> and lamentation.
>
> [2012-07-18 10:45:48 - myapp] Dx 1 error; aborting
>
> [2012-07-18 10:45:48 - myapp] Conversion to Dalvik format
> failed with error 1

This is how my project looks int he explorer:
[image: http://s14.directupload.net/images/120718/zzy6mmym.jpg]

Comment: Can you confirm whether you have not added any jar twice ?

Comment: yes, i think I removed and re-added them 100 times in the last 30 minutes. Nothing is in there twice. but an interessting point, there actually IS a line that says (iaik.xml.crypto.XSecProvider$1) too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the jar you are including has a class in the java.* or javax.* namespace. dx does not allow this, as mentioned in the last big error message.

If you actually need these classes, you'll need to move them to a different package, using something like the jarjar tool. Otherwise, you'll need to remove them from the jar -- it may be possible to have proguard to remove them before everything gets dx'd, I'm not sure.

Comment: can you give me a link or a hint on how to do it with one of your ideas? I think this is going the right way

Comment: @Shehaaz my answer already describes how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem, I finally resolved it by exporting my private library explicitly.

Like:
Project >> properties >> Java Build Path >> Libraries >> Add External Jars.

Note: Removed my all private libraries from libs folder. I know it is not correct but it worked for me.

Thanks,
Anil

Comment: Thanks a ton. This worked for me.) Previously I was using the ant builder which may take 1 to 2 mins for each deploy. Now this saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

Do as follows :

```
project
  > properties
    > java build path
      > libraries
        > remove all including android jars
```

Now, go the project browser, right click on the project you are working on, then

```
android tools
  > fix project properties.
```

Do a clean and then build.

Just restart eclipse, and the error won't occur anymore

Answer (score 1):

If you work on Win7 change this line:

```
call %java_exe% -jar "%PROGUARD_HOME%"\lib\proguard.jar %*
```

in `proguard.bat` file to this:

```
call %java_exe% -jar "%PROGUARD_HOME%"\lib\proguard.jar %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

`proguard.bat` is in:

> [Android SDK Installation Directory]\tools\proguard\bin\proguard.bat

**Edit**:
I hope a combine of these help you:
1-Try to delete `libraries projects` from your project.
2-Try to export your project(as archive file),delete project and it's source from workspace and then import it again.
3-Try to remove your jars from path,do clean-build  and then add them again to your project.

Comment: I already did that, it did not change anything, then i updated my proguard to 4.8, tried to run it - nothing, changed this line again, still does not work

Comment: please see my comment on Halims answer

Comment: 1) as said, there is no thing named like that (see edited question) 2) did not change anything 3) tried already :/

Comment: @billdoor Do you mean that you can not do `clean-build` or export your project,delete it's resource and then import it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when using my own obfuscated lib jar.

my log:

*warning:Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class that doesn't come with an associated EnclosingMethod attribte.This class was probably prouduced by a compiler that did not target the morden .class file format...*

And I solved it like this:before I obfuscate my jar,I added "-keepattributes EnclosingMethod" to the proguard.cfg(or proguard-project.txt in latest android adt version).

Answer (score 0):

Agree with hasanghaforian. The easiest solution is to remove libraries project.
Right click your project->Properties->Java Build Path then remove Library Projects

Comment: i dont't have a folder/item named "Library Projects", i think that was removed 1-2 versions ago

Comment: ps. i added a picture of how the project looks in the package explorer to my question

Comment: @billdoor, not in the explorer. You must right click your project root (parent) then click properties. There you should see Java Build Path.