# ClassNotfoundexception while using viewpager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-view

I was trying implement Viewpager , I have added the external jar required for support. But when I launch the application I am getting a force close. Below is the log.

```
07-20 18:48:00.578: W/dalvikvm(21560): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40019740)
07-20 18:48:00.578: E/AndroidRuntime(21560): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-20 18:48:00.578: E/AndroidRuntime(21560): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.SimpleViewPager/com.example.SimpleViewPager.SimpleViewPagerActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
07-20 18:48:00.578: E/AndroidRuntime(21560):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1668)
07-20 18:48:00.578: E/AndroidRuntime(21560):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1684)
07-20 18:48:00.578: E/AndroidRuntime(21560):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-20 18:48:00.578: E/AndroidRuntime(21560):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
07-20 18:48:00.578: E/AndroidRuntime(21560):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-20 18:48:00.578: E/AndroidRuntime(21560):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-20 18:48:00.578: E/AndroidRuntime(21560):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3750)
07-20 18:48:00.578: E/AndroidRuntime(21560):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-20 18:48:00.578: E/AndroidRuntime(21560):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-20 18:48:00.578: E/AndroidRuntime(21560):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:861)
07-20 18:48:00.578: E/AndroidRuntime(21560):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:619)
07-20 18:48:00.578: E/AndroidRuntime(21560):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-20 18:48:00.578: E/AndroidRuntime(21560): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
07-20 18:48:00.578: E/AndroidRuntime(21560):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
07-20 18:48:00.578: E/AndroidRuntime(21560):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
07-20 18:48:00.578: E/AndroidRuntime(21560):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
07-20 18:48:00.578: E/AndroidRuntime(21560):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
07-20 18:48:00.578: E/AndroidRuntime(21560):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
07-20 18:48:00.578: E/AndroidRuntime(21560):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:224)
07-20 18:48:00.578: E/AndroidRuntime(21560):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1769)
07-20 18:48:00.578: E/AndroidRuntime(21560):    at com.example.SimpleViewPager.SimpleViewPagerActivity.onCreate(SimpleViewPagerActivity.java:18)
07-20 18:48:00.578: E/AndroidRuntime(21560):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-20 18:48:00.578: E/AndroidRuntime(21560):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1632)
07-20 18:48:00.578: E/AndroidRuntime(21560):    ... 11 more
07-20 18:48:00.578: E/AndroidRuntime(21560): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.view.ViewPager in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.SimpleViewPager-1.apk]
07-20 18:48:00.578: E/AndroidRuntime(21560):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
07-20 18:48:00.578: E/AndroidRuntime(21560):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
07-20 18:48:00.578: E/AndroidRuntime(21560):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
07-20 18:48:00.578: E/AndroidRuntime(21560):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
07-20 18:48:00.578: E/AndroidRuntime(21560):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
07-20 18:48:00.578: E/AndroidRuntime(21560):    ... 20 more
07-20 18:48:00.585: D/KeyguardViewMediator(213): setHidden false`
```

Comment: did u add the jar to the build path?

Comment: Yeah i have added , and its appearing in referenced libraries too.. You mean that only right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a `libs` directory in your application package hierarchy.

Put external jar file in it,

Then `Right Click on jar file -> Add to Build Path`..

**Clean** your project and Run again..

Comment: Right click on project or on lib ?

Comment: Now im getting new error while installing it,
[2012-07-20 19:25:00 - SimpleViewPager] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2012-07-20 19:25:00 - SimpleViewPager] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1.   
I tried cleaning and even restarted eclipse

Comment: The problem was i added external jar before and again i added in libs. So i deleted the project and  created new one.Thanks for your help.
This is the question i referred to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar