# Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 when using google-api-java-client library with android

Tags: android, json, google-places-api, java, google-client

I'm following a [sample](http://ddewaele.blogspot.in/2011/05/introducing-google-places-api.html) to learn about the google-api-java-client library. I've downloaded the jars and added them to my libs folder, in my project. During compile time, there are no errors, but when I run the project, I get this error message:

```
Dx trouble processing "javax/transaction/HeuristicCommitException.class":
Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.

This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
going on.

However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
It is also often of questionable legality.

If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.

If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
building an application, then be forewarned that your application
will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
system. You will be to blame for this problem.

If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.

[2012-07-24 12:12:12 - CurrentLocationMapDemo] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2012-07-24 12:12:12 - CurrentLocationMapDemo] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

I've tried other links on SO, but in vain.

**Things that I've tried:**

1. Deleting the project from my workspace.
2. Restarting eclipse in the clean mode.
3. Importing the project, again.
4. Making sure that only android X.X and Android dependencies are present in the build path.

Comment: On what target are you trying to run this (AVD/real device, OS version)?

Comment: Galaxy nexus(real device, android 4.0.4)

Answer (score 1):

After trying out many things, I got it. Initially, what I had done is, I had added all the jar files( the ones I didnt need also). Also, I had not added `libs-sources` folder. On removing unwanted jar files and adding `libs-sources` folder it worked. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

there are many possible reasons for this error:

- double dependency
- proguard problem
- ...
  check out many different "solutions" here:

["Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" on external JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar)

but you could try to check out an android sample for this: 
https://github.com/tuthan/Google-Place-Api-Demo

hth

Comment: I've tried the above mentioned links. Double dependency is not present as I've tried point 4 from my question. proguard is not enabled. I also tried the github example, but it has other issues.

Answer (score 0):

`HeuristicCommitException` is in `transaction-api-1.1.jar`

`QName` is in `xpp3-1.1.4c.jar`

Remove these two jars and things will go.