# Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 - Exporting APK

Tags: android, apk

I want to export an apk for the project but each time i export i got an error saying Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1.
I faced this error before while working on same project and when i get it I go to the project folder and delete jars from folder classes inside folder bin
but in Exporting APK It doesn't work
Can anyone help me ?

Comment: [Have you tried this](http://www.google.com/search?q=Conversion+to+Dalvik+format+failed+with+error+1+-+Exporting+APK&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t)

Comment: I tried but I am using MAC not windows

Comment: [Have a look at this video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4JXGbvgJnSc)

Comment: It didn't help I know how to export and import but I don't know how to fix that error

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Generally my experience with 'Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1' is that you need to do a project clean (if you use eclipse them from menu Project -> Clean ... ) this usually fixes the problem. Also right click on the project you want to export then Properties -> Android Tools -> Fix Project properties.

If this doesn't help you then with terminal go to the project path

```
cd /home/username/your_project_path
```

then

```
rm -fr bin/*
```

Note: you may need to restart eclipse or at least select the project and refresh it (F5).

Hope this will help you, if still doesn't , please let me know

Comment: I am gonna help you with something special in my case. I create a folder called libs inside project and import jars using file system then right click on this folder and configure build path then " Add Jars" not "Add External Jars"

Comment: This always lead to 2 copies of JARS one copy inside folder called libs in the project and other copy inside folder classes inside folder bin in the project

Comment: still getting same error because of 2 copies of JAR files.
can you help to have only 1 copy

Comment: remove all the jar files, then add them from start, and why do not you try add external jars ? with out creating folders by your own

Answer (score 8):

I solved this problem

1. Go to Project » Properties » Java Build Path » Libraries and remove
   all except the "Android X.Y". click OK.
2. Go to Project » Clean » Clean projects selected below » select your
   project and click OK.

That should work.

If you have a JAR file located somewhere in your project folders and THEN added it as a Java Path Library. It does not show up under the Package Explorer, so you don't notice it, but it does get counted twice, causing Dalvik error 1.

Answer (score 3):

You guys don't have to remove libraries at all.

Yes, the problem is caused by the libraries.

BUT!!!
What if you need the libraries to build? It doesn't make sense.

I had a same problem, and finally got the solution.

Add exceptions in the "proguard-project.txt" file having proguard config.

like this

```
-dontwarn android.support.**
```

That's it.

1) check what you have libraries on the project. 
check package name! not file name!
see the list below "Android Dependencies".
when you click "***.jar", 
you can see the package names in the jar file.

Assuming that 
you have "aaa.jar".
the jar have "org.jdesktop.application", "org.jdesktop.swingworker"

```
(Project) > Android Dependencies > aaa.jar > org.jdesktop.application
                                           > org.jdesktop.swingworker
```

2) just add like below

```
-dontwarn org.jdesktop.**
```

into the (Project) > proguard-project.txt file.