# Android, java class not found exception

Tags: java, android

I developed an android application which includes some classes, when I tried to run application I see this in log `Could not find class 'com.voice.NevisaWebService', referenced from method com.voice.Main.upload` but application starts, when I do something in app that needs NevisaWebService class this error appears and application stops working `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.voice.NevisaWebService`, what does it mean? I have this class in my wokspace and everything is write why does this error appears?

here is full logcat:

[image]

Comment: Please post your error from logcat.

Comment: Have you Add that Activity in Menifest file?

Comment: I have just one main activity

Comment: Ok have you Package named Voice? and Where is the class named NavisaWebserice?

Comment: Go to Project--> right click--> Properties--> Java BuildPath--> Order Export--> Tick all check boxes.. Clean Project and Run it again

Comment: if I do that I get this error `Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Go to Project/Properties/Java Build Path/Order and Export -- Make sure there's a check in front of Android Dependencies and the support library, if you use it.Mark all checkboxes.Click on Apply and clean the project.

This worked for me.Hope this helps.

Comment: now I get this error `Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1`

Comment: Did you add any external library?

Comment: yeah, I attached some external library

Comment: Then check all that from checkbox and apply and then clean project.

Comment: I did, and still having same problem

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883178/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-exporting-apk and also this : http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/fix-the-conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-with-adt-14

Comment: Try to delete all the jar file from your java build path and then again attach from lib folder..and then clean the project

Comment: Check this : http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2011/11/android-conversion-to-dalvik-format.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check whether all your Activities included in the AndroidManifest.xml file otherwise add to it.
2. add environment variable for JAVA path from e.g, C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin

Comment: I have just one activity (main), what do you mean by your second way?

Comment: that means setting JAVA_PATH in your system

Comment: right click on 'Computer' from windows start then go to properties, and then advance settings, u'll find environment variable

Answer (score 0):

Check for imports and visibility of class.class  access modifier must be public.and then try to clean and rebuilt.