# Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 :- No solution works

Tags: android, admob, andengine, dalvik

I am adding admob external jar in my project and i am using andengine as a library project but when i try to export the project i get this error. Also adding andengine library project adds andengine.jar also in android dependencies. Is that suppose to happen?

I have tried almost all other answers on stackoverflow but nothing seems to work.

If anyone can help me pls?

Following is my project image

[image: My project screenshot]

Comment: have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar

and this: http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-t8178.html

Comment: this error occurs when you have two libraries of same type included in your project.use only andengine.jar or the andengine library.dont include both of them in your project.

Comment: @viperbone: I tried all solutions in both of these... not working with admob jar.

Comment: @hemanth kumar:- I added only andengine library which is adding andengine.jar to the dependencies folder itself. I am not doing that myself.

Comment: can you post your expanded project folder image?

Comment: I am sort of new to stackoverflow. Can you tell me how to post an image? :-)

Comment: have you tried removing all libraries and readding one by one?

Comment: I have uploaded an image of my project as you asked. Please check.

Comment: yes i have tried removing all libraries and adding one by one. If i don't add admob jar, i can export successfully but as soon i add admob, i get the error. I even tried making a new project and switching the workspace but it doesn't work.

Comment: i think andengine by default have admob references.is your ad visible in your layout when you remove the admob library?

Comment: No. If i remove admob, ads don't render and i get errors on launch because of the missing ad classes

Comment: are you adding the jars from your libs folder?if not add admob and andengine libraries from your libs folder by right-click on the file build path -> add to build path. if you aready did the same way please forgive me..

Comment: i already did that... but thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just solved this problem. I updated my sdk to latest and that solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try exit eclipse, backup if you want, delete gen and bin folders. Start eclipse again, build then export.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens to me after either eclipse has been running for a long time or after I have build a signed apk successfully. To fix it I just restart eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

In `Eclipse`, select the project causing the error- **go to the menu project -> properties -> java build path -> libraries** and remove all jars including the android jars.

Then, right click the project, **go to android tools -> fix project properties**. Then, add back any other external jars you wanted to add to the build path following the **same menu project -> properties -> java build path -> libraries.** To ensure there are no errors due to missing libraries.

Then, do a 'clean' on menu project and build again. It should work.