# How can I sign an XML Document in android with certificate and private key

Tags: java, android

I have a xml document. Now i want sign this document with a certificate and private key in android. I have already done this in java by using javax.xml.crypto package. 
I using same pacakge in android also which is downloaded from http://santuario.apache.org/download.html

But in android it doesn't get compile and gives the following error:
Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

Comment: Did you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar)?

Comment: I don't have these smack.jar and android_maps_lib-1.0.2 jars